# How can I get the message string from std::io::Error?

Tags: rust

This works:

```
format!("{:?}", error)) 
// Os { code: 13, kind: PermissionDenied, message: "Permission denied" }
```

But I want only the `message` field, not the full debug print. How do I get it?

```
error.message // unknown field
error.message() // no method named `message` found for type `std::io::Error` in the current scope
```

Comment: What's really strange is that error.to_string() encloses the message in quotes. This makes testing awkward.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think there's anything that will get you exactly "Permission denied". The closest I know of is the `Display` implementation of the `Error`, which still includes the underlying error code:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::error::Error;

fn main() {
    let error = File::open("/does-not-exist").unwrap_err();

    println!("{:?}", error);
    // Error { repr: Os { code: 2, message: "No such file or directory" } }

    println!("{}", error);
    // No such file or directory (os error 2)

    println!("{}", error.description());
    // entity not found
}
```

If this is suitable, you can use `error.to_string()`.

---

The standard library gets this string from `sys::os`, which gets defined based on the platform. For example, [on UNIX-like platforms, it uses `strerror_r`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.24.1/src/libstd/sys/unix/os.rs#L88). This function does not appear to be exposed in any public fashion, however.

Comment: OP can get `PermissionDenied` by doing `error.kind()`, which should give [`std::io::ErrorKind::PermissionDenied`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/enum.ErrorKind.html#variant.PermissionDenied), though this does not give the message field.